# Where is BitmapImage / System.Windows.Media.Imaging?

Tags: windows-8

I want to Change the source of an Image programmatically.

I found that it's done with help of the class BitmapImage. The class is in System.Windows.Media.Imaging

But I don't have this package! I suppose I have to install something, but I don't know what and how. Searching also didn't help, I only find examples using this class, but not how to get the package. I'm using a fresh installation of Visual Studio Express 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` is part of WPF and cannot be used in a Windows Store app.  Perhaps you are looking for [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR243235).